# Webkit Keyframes on Hover - Prevent Previous Animation

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-animations, webkit-animation

I have an element that I have a set of @-webkit-keyframes to animate in. On page load, these keyframes run, and the intro looks great.

Next, I have a second set of @-webkit-keyframes on hover and set to repeat, so on hover, that element has a looping animation. That also works great.

However, the instant I move the mouse away from the element, the first (intro) set of keyframes gets run again. I don't want it to run after it first runs. Is there an easy way to prevent this in CSS?

Minimal example of what I have

```
#e { -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out 0.5s; } /* Fades in on load, BUT gets called when mouse moves away as well */
#e:hover { -webkit-animation: pulse 1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; } /* Works fine, pulses on hover */
```

Also, can someone with 1500+ reputation edit the tags and add the webkit-animation tag? I can't believe it hasn't been created yet… :\

Comment: There you go. It's quite a common topic too.

Comment: try using transitions instead of animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no pure CSS way of accomplishing what you need. You can add the animation to a parent element or to a wrapper and animate each element separately:

```
.wrapper {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn .5s ease-out 0 1;
}
#e { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
#e:hover { 
    -webkit-animation: pulse 100ms ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0.5;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
        0%   { background-color: #000; }
        100% { background-color: #c00; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3PuT2/

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit disappointing it's not possible with pure CSS but that works well. One thing to note is that I needed to use `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` in order to make it look right (I use 3d transforms and perspective).